# find() usage in C++ stl

Tags: c++, syntax, stl, find

I have been implementing C++ STL `set<>` and I am having trouble in using `find()` function.

Below is my `set<>` type so that I can store three integers a,b,c.

```
set<pair<int,pair<int,int> > > myset;
```

1) How to use `find()` in it."Do I need to pass my own comparator function here as we do in sort()".

2) Also how will `set<>` keep the distinctness of the set.
I mean I want the set containing

`{ {1,2,3}; {2,3,4} ; {2,3,1} }` elements if I insert:-

```
{1,2,3}

{2,3,4} 

{1,2,3}

{2,3,1}
```

Comment: Use `std::set`'s `find` member function.

Comment: implementing `set` or using it?

Comment: I can't use directly the find(), Its gives Error. :( ..I think we need to pass comparator in it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use a tuple instead of a pair< int, pair > ? (See the end of the answer)

If you can't (because you're not using C++11), to use find with your pairs, you don't need your comparators :

```
typedef pair<int,pair<int,int>>  my_type;
typedef set<my_type> set_of_mytype;
set_of_mytype myset; 
myset.insert(make_pair(1,make_pair(3,4))); 


set_of_mytype::iterator search1 = myset.find(make_pair(1,make_pair(5,4))); 
set_of_mytype::iterator search2 = myset.find(make_pair(1,make_pair(3,4))); 


if(search1 != myset.end())
  cout << "search 1: (1,(5,4)) found !" << endl;
if(search2 != myset.end())
  cout << "search 2: (1,(3,4)) found !" << endl;

cout << " Size of the set with only (1,(3,4)) in it : "<< myset.size() << endl;
 myset.insert(make_pair(3,make_pair(1,4))); 
cout << " Size of the set with only (1,(3,4)) and (3,(1,4)) in it : "<< myset.size() << endl;
```

Will output :

> search 2: (1,(3,4)) found !
>
> Size of the set with only (1,(3,4)) in it : 1
>
> Size of the set with only (1,(3,4)) and (3,(1,4)) in it : 2

So for your first question : without custom comparator it works.

For the second one, if you try inserting again :

```
myset.insert(make_pair(1,make_pair(3,4))); 
cout << " Size of the set is still : "<< myset.size() << endl;
```

The output is

> Size of the set is still : 2

So the "distinctiveness" will be present here.

---

If you are compiling with C++11, you can use tuples :

```
 typedef tuple <int,int,int> my_type2;
 typedef set<my_type2> set_of_tuples;
 set_of_tuples myset2;
 myset2.insert(make_tuple(1,3,4));
```

your code will be easier : writing make_tuple(1,3,4) is easier than make_pair(1,make_pair(3,4)).
Plus acessing the element with this will be easier :

```
set_of_tuples::iterator it = my_set.find( make_tuple(1,3,4) )
my_type2 my_element = *it
cout << get<0>(my_element) << "," <<  get<1>(my_element) << ","  get<2>(my_element) << endl;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for then :) .That way if I am given many triangles with their sides(a,b,c). I can tell number of distinct triangles.